# upload mp4 via ajax to mvc controller failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, video

I am uploading mp4 to my mvc controller, but Ajax returns this error:"Error  error Not Found undefined"
My view

```
<form id="CrearRecurso">
<div class="container">      
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Imagen)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Imagen, new { type = "file", name = "Imagen" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Imagen)
    </div>
    <button id="submiter" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear recurso!</button>
</div>
```

This is my ajax part, where I call my API. But I am getting an error that you will see below after the code.

```
$('#CrearRecurso').submit(function (e) {              
            var formData = new FormData($('#CrearRecurso').get(0));
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            var files = $("#Imagen").get(0).files;
            var name = files.name;
            if (files.length > 0) { //checks if there is a file 

                if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: '/api/mycontroller/Create?MyId=' + LeccionId,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (result) {
                            //do something 
                          
                        },
                    error: function (ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }
                    });
                }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

When I upload pdf or jpg it is okay, but when I use mp4 files, I get this error in the alert.
[image: error I get when uploading mp4 files]

The model related to the file upload is the following:

```
 [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Imagen { get; set; }
```

Why is it happening this? thank you.

Update 1: my file size is about 50mb. Could it be related with the problem?

Comment: For a start your not cancelling the default submit so you making a GET to the method that generated the view plus your ajax call

Comment: `'/api/mycontroller/Create?MyId=' + LeccionId` => from your error it doesn't hit that action method, is that `LeccionId` null or empty? The popup appears because your AJAX call returns error response & hitting `alert(ts.responseText)`.

Comment: Tetsuya, actually it is calling the api without no problems when I use pdf or jpg, but for mp4 I get that error

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I could see that the files I wanted to upload had a lenght greater than 4mb, what I had to do is to change the web.config to allow api requests.

Please, refer to this answer: [Dealing with large files in asp.Net API](https://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/)